# Is it possible to show contents of file without download file on Azure Portal Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm working with Azure. I have successfully upload `.csv` file. Then, I have opened my Azure portal.

In **container**, my file is showing, but when I click on that file, **Blob properties** seen. but I don't see content of file. Then, I have to download the file to see contents.

Is it possible to show contents of a file without downloading the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to show contents of file without download file on Azure
>   Portal Storage account?

As of today, no. The portal does not have this feature and you would need to download the file to see its contents.

In any case, if you're planning to view the contents of a blob (say in a browser) the browser needs to download the file before it can display its contents as the browser is running on your computer and the blob is residing at some remote location. This is very much similar to how the browser displays the images. It actually downloads the images from a remote server and then displays it.

Comment: Thank you sir. one more question: Can I see content of table in Azure portal?

Comment: I have successfully created table. When I open table opn Azure account, I see only table name and URL. So, How to see table content?

Comment: Sorry, no :(. However there are many storage explorers available (both free & commercial) that you can use to view table data. Please see this link for a list of storage explorers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-explorers.